# Is there a way to highlight the clicked mat-grid-tile? When each mat-grid-tile is dynamically generated

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, angular6

I'm dynamically showing mat-grid-tile in a mat-grid-list in the UI whose number and data vary as to their values change in the back end. They're dynamically generated. A Click on anyone mat-grid-tile invokes a function and passes a data to it to proceed. I want to identify the mat-grid-tile which has been clicked and keep it highlighted until the user is routed to another page.

I've tried mat-grid-tile:active{background-color: #333} which changed the background color for a second just as a flash when the user clicks and not after.

{{tile.Name}}

I expect the output of the tile being highlighted with the changed background color for the rest of the time until the user is kicked out of this page or div.

Answer (score 0):

In `html` file:

```
<mat-grid-title (click)="highlight($event)">...</mat-grid-title>
```

In `ts` file:

```
public highlight(ev) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;

  target.classList.add("bg-blue");

  myOldDataProcessingFunction();
}
```

this way you can get the element. Now you could set change the style or add another class.